# Decimal list to float list in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list from mssql query which includes Decimals. Such as:

```
 [(1, Decimal('33.00'), Decimal('5.30'), Decimal('50.00')),
  (2, Decimal('17.00'), Decimal('0.50'), Decimal('10.00'))]
```

I want to transform that to dict and float number like that:

```
 {1: [33.00, 5.30, 50.00],
  2: [17.00, 0.50, 10.00]}
```

I writed below line:

```
load_dict = {key: values for key, *values in dataRead}
```

which results:

```
{1: [Decimal('33.00'), Decimal('105.30'), Decimal('25650.00')],
 2: [Decimal('17.00'), Decimal('40.50'), Decimal('10000.00')]}
```

I am asking that is there anyway making this transformation with list/dict comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) to values:

```
from decimal import Decimal

data = [(1, Decimal('33.00'), Decimal('5.30'), Decimal('50.00')),
  (2, Decimal('17.00'), Decimal('0.50'), Decimal('10.00'))]

load_dict = {key: list(map(float, values))  for key, *values in data}

print(load_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{1: [33.0, 5.3, 50.0], 2: [17.0, 0.5, 10.0]}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use a dict-comprehension with a cast to `float` like this:

```
from decimal import Decimal

lst = [(1, Decimal('33.00'), Decimal('5.30'), Decimal('50.00')),
  (2, Decimal('17.00'), Decimal('0.50'), Decimal('10.00'))]

ret = {key: [float(f) for f in values] for key, *values in lst}
print(ret)
# {1: [33.0, 5.3, 50.0], 2: [17.0, 0.5, 10.0]}
```

Comment: Your way is also simple but daniel answer not use "for loop". Therefore it seems more compact. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: List comprehensions with `for` are generally preferred over `map` these days.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Is there significant performance difference? And If you add reference, I can look.

Comment: See: [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)